# Functions with differentials that are "close" to the unit matrix.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

The inverse function theorem was recently introduced at school and the following lemma was used in its proof:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb R^k$ be an open set and let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$. Let $g: U \to \mathbb R^k$ be continuously differentiable for all $y \in U$.
> If $\Vert Dg_y - I \Vert _{op} \le \epsilon$ and $B_r(x) \subset U$, then:
> $$ B_{(1-\epsilon)r}(g(x)) \subset g(B_r(x)) \subset B_{(1+\epsilon)r}(g(x))$$

Is there any intuitive or geometric way to think of this?
I tried to come up with examples of $g$ myself, like defining $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ by $g(x,y) = (\frac{3}{2}x, \frac{3}{2}y)$ - it fulfills the condition with $\epsilon  = \frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not sure what the sequence of containments mean.

Any help would be  very much appreciated.